# Coupled nonlinear differential system with discontinuous functions which values are given by list elements, boundary conditions, NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, nonlinear, discontinuity

[image]
I am very new to mathematica, I have googled my problem in vain, hope you can help me.
I am currently trying to solve a non linear system of two coupled differential equations given by (41) and (42). All variables depend on k (alpha, theta, xhi, phi, as well as the matrix elements A11, A22, A12, and A21). Eta is a fixed arbitrary parameter.

I have started by calculating all matrix elements for k in a certain range (say k0 to k1) with step s=(k1-k0)/N. so that I have N 2x2 matrices A[k0], A[k0+s]...A[k1].

My problem is that when I define my system of equation on mathematica as well as the following boundary conditions on alpha (alpha[k0]==pi/8 ; alpha[k1]==pi/8 ) (and none on theta because I do not care about it for the moment : it's a free parameter), I always get an error message which is basically related to the fact that when K varies in the NDSOLVE problem, the matrix elements are not retrieved, instead of getting something like A12[k] I get something like A12[$NDSOLVE1245845] which is not a valid part specification for a list.

I have tried summarizing my problem the way I understand it, but here is the code if you wanna try it yourself.

I have copied my mathematica notebook here, I give you the A matrices in the beginning, it's not very good looking so I can send the notebook  directly if someone wants it.

```
 (*Here is a list of lists called aMat, each element \
aMat[[k]] corresponds to one of the matrices 2x2 A(k) matrix in the \
equations, the process leading to aMat is kinda long so I do not post \
it here!  *)

Nsite = 51;
etad = \[Pi]/4;
d = 532*10^-9;

 aMat = {{{8.033808200646101`*^-21 + 
      1.0195947261614721`*^-7 I, -2.259193402732543`*^-14 + 
      5.6606425073577124`*^-8 I}, {-5.579587617378922`*^-14 - 
      1.3979370715909291`*^-7 I, -2.6939288474872005`*^-18 - 
      1.1360855346370705`*^-7 I}}, {{4.920008417679118`*^-21 + 
      2.864988207444914`*^-7 I, 
     6.448591285746703`*^-14 + 
      1.615615344995959`*^-7 I}, {-2.626485508352081`*^-19 - 
      6.4559205290202805`*^-9 I, 
     4.02818142522391`*^-15 + 
      1.0091758074619052`*^-8 I}}, {{9.701612357018`*^-21 + 
      2.8808758498493`*^-7 I, 
     4.941191381151055`*^-18 + 
      1.5994433204297324`*^-7 I}, {-2.612213198258168`*^-19 - 
      1.2747464222971996`*^-8 I, 
     7.580144893918093`*^-19 + 
      1.9940869401651616`*^-8 I}}, {{1.4215083632434476`*^-20 + 
      2.9067525276121966`*^-7 I, 
     2.769500855905615`*^-18 + 
      1.5731234585782317`*^-7 I}, {-2.588987808569906`*^-19 - 
      1.871924893424333`*^-8 I, 
     6.580740142263754`*^-19 + 
      2.9316926956117847`*^-8 I}}, {{1.8346598707244687`*^-20 + 
      2.94176405812251`*^-7 I, 
     1.9604382654454056`*^-18 + 
      1.5375525696154838`*^-7 I}, {-2.5576628331274985`*^-19 - 
      2.423282541976617`*^-8 I, 
     6.265767976797439`*^-19 + 
      3.8012641902104256`*^-8 I}}, {{2.200384369841378`*^-20 + 
      2.984806514429946`*^-7 I, 
     1.523813781806201`*^-18 + 
      1.493887717289512`*^-7 I}, {-2.5193244339608564`*^-19 - 
      2.9172715176654585`*^-8 I, 
     6.095502396476031`*^-19 + 
      4.585226440947448`*^-8 I}}, {{2.5119152956265407`*^-20 + 
      3.0346017235825585`*^-7 I, 
     1.247497168319565`*^-18 + 
      1.443465362831549`*^-7 I}, {-2.4753336539568484`*^-19 - 
      3.345006505614873`*^-8 I, 
     5.9721585438584`*^-19 + 
      5.269690247822571`*^-8 I}}, {{2.7650213281433854`*^-20 + 
      3.0897752252144107`*^-7 I, 
     1.0566155606811343`*^-18 + 
      1.3877179229760157`*^-7 I}, {-2.426853865088762`*^-19 - 
      3.700384427991734`*^-8 I, 
     5.867343436946562`*^-19 + 
      5.844660952900648`*^-8 I}}, {{2.9578655420869275`*^-20 + 
      3.148928398202045`*^-7 I, 
     9.172964717301432`*^-19 + 
      1.328096678093049`*^-7 I}, {-2.375378134195755`*^-19 - 
      3.979986495755983`*^-8 I, 
     5.770644027762974`*^-19 + 
      6.303956594952819`*^-8 I}}, {{3.090708773872836`*^-20 + 
      3.210698904499792`*^-7 I, 
     8.121591406248909`*^-19 + 
      1.2660073581881407`*^-7 I}, {-2.32199340437251`*^-19 - 
      4.182814287649467`*^-8 I, 
     5.678643893447754`*^-19 + 
      6.644898914789824`*^-8 I}}, {{3.165520994795495`*^-20 + 
      3.2738064259815684`*^-7 I, 
     7.311146538100815`*^-19 + 
      1.2027616963291322`*^-7 I}, {-2.268068980986546`*^-19 - 
      4.3099210077193304`*^-8 I, 
     5.59006120501795`*^-19 + 
      6.867854226800027`*^-8 I}}, {{3.185560132672103`*^-20 + 
      3.3370832173128694`*^-7 I, 
     6.681804660377018`*^-19 + 
      1.1395454856529243`*^-7 I}, {-2.2145281297650666`*^-19 - 
      4.363996434159545`*^-8 I, 
     5.505167839307502`*^-19 + 
      6.975699420756697`*^-8 I}}, {{3.1549654442220284`*^-20 + 
      3.399490870570553`*^-7 I, 
     6.194946126444731`*^-19 + 
      1.0774016379153097`*^-7 I}, {-2.162334268759257`*^-19 - 
      4.348953406727124`*^-8 I, 
     5.424303799691056`*^-19 + 
      6.973276185751127`*^-8 I}}, {{3.072979637965408`*^-20 + 
      3.460125773063581`*^-7 I, 
     5.826703023850006`*^-19 + 
      1.0172255486431532`*^-7 I}, {-2.1121053091407048`*^-19 - 
      4.2695495500116656`*^-8 I, 
     5.348145787220257`*^-19 + 
      6.866879461775877`*^-8 I}}, {{2.9583840885090626`*^-20 + 
      3.51821613085182`*^-7 I, 
     5.562736834605877`*^-19 + 
      9.597696338490143`*^-8 I}, {-2.0646443809917233`*^-19 - 
      4.131063934935675`*^-8 I, 
     5.277372434606911`*^-19 + 
      6.663808654963002`*^-8 I}}, {{2.8044775908692463`*^-20 + 
      3.5731133206229025`*^-7 I, 
     5.397324217219753`*^-19 + 
      9.056540111771756`*^-8 I}, {-2.0200689167033389`*^-19 - 
      3.939036686209166`*^-8 I, 
     5.212818970912487`*^-19 + 
      6.371995170785319`*^-8 I}}, {{2.6247451780140498`*^-20 + 
      3.6242799318184524`*^-7 I, 
     5.331247036562746`*^-19 + 
      8.553807289819507`*^-8 I}, {-1.9791340461962209`*^-19 - 
      3.699071121991565`*^-8 I, 
     5.15548745722521`*^-19 + 
      5.999708615932234`*^-8 I}}, {{2.4090528817032664`*^-20 + 
      3.6712763421650144`*^-7 I, 
     5.375201785758898`*^-19 + 
      8.093495114976781`*^-8 I}, {-1.9417830755396824`*^-19 - 
      3.4166927276595516`*^-8 I, 
     5.106517303262318`*^-19 + 
      5.5553366763549385`*^-8 I}}, {{2.1736332854480823`*^-20 + 
      3.7137471524357817`*^-7 I, 
     5.552884482597155`*^-19 + 
      7.678735560534001`*^-8 I}, {-1.9083153269163605`*^-19 - 
      3.097256626088577`*^-8 I, 
     5.067908381052614`*^-19 + 
      5.047229628922304`*^-8 I}}, {{1.918972443974762`*^-20 + 
      3.751408356668874`*^-7 I, 
     5.908999847273977`*^-19 + 
      7.311944143641007`*^-8 I}, {-1.8789836409047963`*^-19 - 
      2.745894444955685`*^-8 I, 
     5.042625743532527`*^-19 + 
      4.483598845297464`*^-8 I}}, {{1.6484488934489734`*^-20 + 
      3.784035769353109`*^-7 I, 
     6.531992545271056`*^-19 + 
      6.994953833221866`*^-8 I}, {-1.8537189059701642`*^-19 - 
      2.3674918938353474`*^-8 I, 
     5.036732002915816`*^-19 + 
      3.872458668850092`*^-8 I}}, {{1.3651087345306606`*^-20 + 
      3.81145497297622`*^-7 I, 
     7.607243135375442`*^-19 + 
      6.72913118158307`*^-8 I}, {-1.8326259355206506`*^-19 - 
      1.9666894588395473`*^-8 I, 
     5.063833558236244`*^-19 + 
      3.221602008658648`*^-8 I}}, {{1.071702867170963`*^-20 + 
      3.833532875741768`*^-7 I, 
     9.597905062862139`*^-19 + 
      6.515473744661214`*^-8 I}, {-1.8157473867785008`*^-19 - 
      1.5478999238071165`*^-8 I, 
     5.162604364852125`*^-19 + 
      2.538601387320923`*^-8 I}}, {{7.70733053769387`*^-21 + 
      3.85017086373458`*^-7 I, 
     1.4104236563210386`*^-18 + 
      6.35468903630958`*^-8 I}, {-1.803060954271949`*^-19 - 
      1.1153377614241531`*^-8 I, 
     5.487471866782634`*^-19 + 
      1.8308286752025182`*^-8 I}}, {{4.6450348089588645`*^-21 + 
      3.861299476885155`*^-7 I, 
     3.45777828374654`*^-18 + 
      6.247255872771278`*^-8 I}, {-1.7946103885000363`*^-19 - 
      6.730566203934185`*^-9 I, 
     7.543375479191052`*^-19 + 
      1.1054881348791118`*^-8 I}}, {{1.5517555266936961`*^-21 + 
      3.866874519217884`*^-7 I, 
     1.894536140693539`*^-18 - 
      6.193469167651351`*^-8 I}, {-1.7903838116380825`*^-19 - 
      2.249921164821364`*^-9 I, -2.9423700996263846`*^-20 - 
      3.696585844110595`*^-9 I}}, {{-1.5637272016006697`*^-21 + 
      3.866874519218525`*^-7 I, -1.8945280793554763`*^-18 - 
      6.193469167662479`*^-8 I}, {1.790388518851441`*^-19 - 
      2.2499211668119864`*^-9 I, 
     2.942484092397458`*^-20 - 
      3.6965858435714946`*^-9 I}}, {{-4.742174432805856`*^-21 + 
      3.861299476885976`*^-7 I, -3.457798716561031`*^-18 + 
      6.247255872778867`*^-8 I}, {1.794622002239326`*^-19 - 
      6.730566202745649`*^-9 I, -7.543402900929096`*^-19 + 
      1.105488134876665`*^-8 I}}, {{-7.804190196500871`*^-21 + 
      3.850170863734963`*^-7 I, -1.41042949354795`*^-18 + 
      6.354689036299113`*^-8 I}, {1.8030775562086866`*^-19 - 
      1.1153377613396663`*^-8 I, -5.487469877992032`*^-19 + 
      1.830828675237706`*^-8 I}}, {{-1.072217587355892`*^-20 + 
      3.833532875741192`*^-7 I, -9.597948862826747`*^-19 + 
      6.515473744655095`*^-8 I}, {1.815736973880872`*^-19 - 
      1.547899923794939`*^-8 I, -5.162600944513975`*^-19 + 
      2.5386013873208913`*^-8 I}}, {{-1.355788229112468`*^-20 + 
      3.811454972975411`*^-7 I, -7.60714470754315`*^-19 + 
      6.729131181592481`*^-8 I}, {1.8326086245605312`*^-19 - 
      1.9666894589467598`*^-8 I, -5.063836859354622`*^-19 + 
      3.221602008635054`*^-8 I}}, {{-1.6414597680533996`*^-20 + 
      3.7840357693517435`*^-7 I, -6.531898766876434`*^-19 + 
      6.99495383323809`*^-8 I}, {1.8537175483580718`*^-19 - 
      2.367491893831529`*^-8 I, -5.036749390236897`*^-19 + 
      3.8724586688078445`*^-8 I}}, {{-1.921725421279006`*^-20 + 
      3.751408356667764`*^-7 I, -5.909171207125913`*^-19 + 
      7.31194414365596`*^-8 I}, {1.878974717179978`*^-19 - 
      2.7458944450273424`*^-8 I, -5.04268334534577`*^-19 + 
      4.483598845268152`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.1777458316409858`*^-20 + 
      3.7137471524352475`*^-7 I, -5.552957621470693`*^-19 + 
      7.678735560547088`*^-8 I}, {1.9083440519447586`*^-19 - 
      3.0972566261077335`*^-8 I, -5.067947372672451`*^-19 + 
      5.0472296289018394`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.4168302854081965`*^-20 + 
      3.6712763421628677`*^-7 I, -5.375185227215908`*^-19 + 
      8.093495114988769`*^-8 I}, {1.9418863411275705`*^-19 - 
      3.4166927275981066`*^-8 I, -5.106556154321534`*^-19 + 
      5.5553366763138164`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.632817352120827`*^-20 + 
      3.624279931815362`*^-7 I, -5.331568308207647`*^-19 + 
      8.55380728985272`*^-8 I}, {1.9791371594348603`*^-19 - 
      3.6990711221359786`*^-8 I, -5.155584220640963`*^-19 + 
      5.999708615869976`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.818109962336356`*^-20 + 
      3.5731133206196647`*^-7 I, -5.397246617010634`*^-19 + 
      9.05654011181913`*^-8 I}, {2.0202438086576516`*^-19 - 
      3.939036686264893`*^-8 I, -5.21280417895509`*^-19 + 
      6.3719951707024`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.9586895515665964`*^-20 + 
      3.5182161308500464`*^-7 I, -5.562991385562087`*^-19 + 
      9.597696338517826`*^-8 I}, {2.0645434923365562`*^-19 - 
      4.131063934951449`*^-8 I, -5.277380643708293`*^-19 + 
      6.663808654914656`*^-8 I}}, {{-3.0676690533857427`*^-20 + 
      3.4601257730656186`*^-7 I, -5.826255321520116`*^-19 + 
      1.0172255486428117`*^-7 I}, {2.1121226387071561`*^-19 - 
      4.2695495500631116`*^-8 I, -5.347976825781128`*^-19 + 
      6.866879461805875`*^-8 I}}, {{-3.1413633840733296`*^-20 + 
      3.399490870573189`*^-7 I, -6.194822088499933`*^-19 + 
      1.0774016379118343`*^-7 I}, {2.1621455849783666`*^-19 - 
      4.348953406570069`*^-8 I, -5.424199991009962`*^-19 + 
      6.973276185810851`*^-8 I}}, {{-3.176580420118423`*^-20 + 
      3.337083217314582`*^-7 I, -6.6816170131315625`*^-19 + 
      1.1395454856494644`*^-7 I}, {2.2144503793694587`*^-19 - 
      4.363996434169416`*^-8 I, -5.505116398374329`*^-19 + 
      6.975699420819069`*^-8 I}}, {{-3.158091513129204`*^-20 + 
      3.273806425978735`*^-7 I, -7.311116952049515`*^-19 + 
      1.20276169633033`*^-7 I}, {2.268030718650996`*^-19 - 
      4.30992100768835`*^-8 I, -5.590139197241613`*^-19 + 
      6.867854226744586`*^-8 I}}, {{-3.084553118990792`*^-20 + 
      3.2106989044961364`*^-7 I, -8.121317943872537`*^-19 + 
      1.2660073581925464`*^-7 I}, {2.3219598122734736`*^-19 - 
      4.182814287779874`*^-8 I, -5.678574394024991`*^-19 + 
      6.64489891468643`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.9586960811889886`*^-20 + 
      3.148928398201589`*^-7 I, -9.172923860730165`*^-19 + 
      1.3280966780965467`*^-7 I}, {2.375323980492081`*^-19 - 
      3.9799864958056516`*^-8 I, -5.770522232961653`*^-19 + 
      6.30395659489623`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.773639454812924`*^-20 + 
      3.089775225213917`*^-7 I, -1.0565548046853918`*^-18 + 
      1.3877179229758124`*^-7 I}, {2.4268947069842577`*^-19 - 
      3.70038442782392`*^-8 I, -5.866989037626828`*^-19 + 
      5.844660952881337`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.5219765064266593`*^-20 + 
      3.0346017235835437`*^-7 I, -1.2475239204315625`*^-18 + 
      1.4434653628306901`*^-7 I}, {2.475259145231046`*^-19 - 
      3.345006505766175`*^-8 I, -5.97196411162458`*^-19 + 
      5.269690247871184`*^-8 I}}, {{-2.201120865499778`*^-20 + 
      2.984806514432385`*^-7 I, -1.523749426424153`*^-18 + 
      1.49388771728884`*^-7 I}, {2.5193381479359126`*^-19 - 
      2.9172715176301558`*^-8 I, -6.095315110032011`*^-19 + 
      4.585226441016985`*^-8 I}}, {{-1.8296693643235808`*^-20 + 
      2.9417640581247653`*^-7 I, -1.960411302002763`*^-18 + 
      1.537552569612602`*^-7 I}, {2.5576456729892`*^-19 - 
      2.4232825419138733`*^-8 I, -6.265738883668753`*^-19 + 
      3.80126419035277`*^-8 I}}, {{-1.4165772515444426`*^-20 + 
      2.906752527612242`*^-7 I, -2.7694897162441683`*^-18 + 
      1.5731234585759723`*^-7 I}, {2.5889508004545654`*^-19 - 
      1.871924893406248`*^-8 I, -6.580711156897425`*^-19 + 
      2.9316926956975514`*^-8 I}}, {{-9.677807805559877`*^-21 + 
      2.8808758498495014`*^-7 I, -4.9411868928239335`*^-18 + 
      1.5994433204294002`*^-7 I}, {2.612202665348913`*^-19 - 
      1.2747464224024206`*^-8 I, -7.580139298539908`*^-19 + 
      1.9940869402047568`*^-8 I}}, {{-4.89633514500996`*^-21 + 
      2.8649882074453543`*^-7 I, -6.44858048312444`*^-14 + 
      1.615615344996214`*^-7 I}, {2.626485507944989`*^-19 - 
      6.455920528462238`*^-9 I, -4.0281746783825426`*^-15 + 
      1.0091758074771626`*^-8 I}}, {{-8.02538333405992`*^-21 + 
      1.0195947261628438`*^-7 I, 
     2.2591971871808648`*^-14 + 
      5.660642507341513`*^-8 I}, {5.5795782702384586`*^-14 - 
      1.3979370715915536`*^-7 I, 
     2.5420215571980736`*^-18 - 1.136085534636542`*^-7 I}}};

 aMat[[52]](*2x2 matrix*)

Out[24]= {{-8.02538*10^-21 + 1.01959*10^-7 I, 
  2.2592*10^-14 + 5.66064*10^-8 I}, {5.57958*10^-14 - 1.39794*10^-7 I,
   2.54202*10^-18 - 1.13609*10^-7 I}}

 aMat[[1]](*2x2 matrix*)

Out[5]= {{8.03381*10^-21 + 1.01959*10^-7 I, -2.25919*10^-14 + 
   5.66064*10^-8 I}, {-5.57959*10^-14 - 
   1.39794*10^-7 I, -2.69393*10^-18 - 1.13609*10^-7 I}}

(*I define my equations here, notice that I call \
aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi]+1)*Nsite)/2+1]], that is because in NDSolve k \
varies between -\[Pi]/d to \[Pi]/d, this function gives the \
corresponding matrix element, for example \[Pi]/d will give 52, \
already here the definitionf of eqn1 and eqn2 gives an error !!!*)

 eqn1 = 
  a'[k]/2 == -(Cos[2 t[k]]/
      Sin[t[k]])*(Re[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Cos[
         etad] + Im[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Sin[
         etad]) - 
    1/(Tan[a[k]/2] Tan[
       t[k]])*(Re[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Sin[
         etad] - Im[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Cos[
         etad]) + 
    Cos[t[k]] (aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 1]] - 
       aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[2, 2]]);


 eqn2 = 
  t'[k]/2 == (Cos[t[k]] Sin[a[k]])/
     Sin[a[k]/
      2]^2*(Re[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Cos[
         etad] + Im[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Sin[
         etad]) - 
    Cos[a[k]]/
     Sin[a[k]/
      2]^2*(Re[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Sin[
         etad] - Im[
         aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 2]]] Cos[
         etad]) + 
    1/Tan[a[k]/2] Sin[
      t[k]]*(aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[1, 1]] - 
       aMat[[Round[((d*k/\[Pi] + 1)*Nsite)/2 + 1]]][[2, 2]]);


(*boundary conditions*)

 eqn = {eqn1, eqn2};

 bcs = {a[-\[Pi]/d] == \[Pi]/8, a[\[Pi]/d] == \[Pi]/8};


 system = Join[eqn, bcs];
sol = NDSolve[system, a, {k, -\[Pi]/d, \[Pi]/d}];
```

And the error log (the first message up to the Part::partw: Part 2 of Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 [Pi]))] does not exist message are due to the definition of eqn1 and eqn2, basically k is not a number ... the last message comes from NDSOLVE):

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] cannot be used as a part specification.

General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

Part::partw: Part 2 of Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] does not exist.

Part::pkspec1: The expression Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] cannot be used as a part specification.

General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

Part::partw: Part 2 of Round[1+51/2 (1+(133 k)/(250000000 \[Pi]))] does not exist.

NDSolve::bvdisc: NDSolve is not currently able to solve boundary value problems with discrete variables.
```

You will notice that this is not the error message I have complained about, this i because I have stripped the problem of all superfluous parameters, this is the base error message, it seems related to the fact that the A function is discontinuous; I dont see why it should be a problem especially since  these kind of algorithms are based on discretization methods (?).

As a precision, in my problem k is in fact discrete it goes from -pi/d to pi/d  with step 2pi/(N*d), where d is a certain distance, and N an arbitrary number....

I am kind of fed up with this, I thought it would be straight forward, I thank you for any help you can provide. Since I am new to mathematica and equation solving, I would also appreciate pointing out bad practices (except for the aMat definition of course), and pointers on the Method options of NDSOLVE(I tried a few kind of randomly). Thank you very much, of course if you can solve the equations in any other way please do not hesitate to share your solution !

Comment: "All variables depend on k (alpha, theta, xhi, phi, as well as the matrix elements A11, A22, A12, and A21). ……I have started by calculating all matrix elements for k in a certain range (say k0 to k1) with step s=(k1-k0)/N. so that I have N 2x2 matrices A[k0], A[k0+s]...A[k1]…" You should not. Directly use the symbolic 2*2 A matrix instead should resolve the problem. If you cannot (e.g. because it's from complicated calculation) at least build an `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: the A matrices indeed come from a complicated calculation that starts with finding the eingenvalues of a certain hamiltonian... I'll try the interpolatingFunction idea, thanks for your help